# Can the computational result of an expression in a condition be returned in C++

Tags: c++, function, return, return-value

```
f(-1);

int f(int a) {
    return (a%2) ? (a%2) : (a*2);
}
```

Consider the above function `f()` , `a%2` is returned if `a%2` is evaluated to non-zero.

**QUESTION :** **Are there any advance operator or expression that can merge the condition and return value and form something like**

```
return (a%2) OR (a*2)  // underlying logic is return (a%2) ? (a%2) : (a*2);
```

I understand that I have provided one possible solution `return (a%2) ? (a%2) : (a*2);` already but I want to explorer more on C++ so I ask this question. This question is simply a Yes/No question. I am expecting answers other then using if-else statement

My thought :

`a%2` in a condition is evaluated and converted to type `bool` so it is no way to cast back to corresponding `int` value.

Comment: `return (a+1) ? (a+1) : 0;` is equal to `return a+1;`

Comment: Yes you guys are correct, but the motivation of this question is try to find out any uncommon operator or expression in C++

Comment: @Biboo Unfortunate example. Use a variable to store the result of more complex calculations.

Comment: @Slave Thanks for your comment, I redefine my question in order to make it clear.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I get what you're asking, but some compilers have an extension where `a ?: b` is equivalent to `a ? a : b`, but with `a` being evaluated only once, I think.

Comment: @chris YES! I'm expecting some answer like this. However, `a ?: b` is not standard C++, right?

Comment: @BibooChung, No, it is not. I'd find it useful, but there's no standard operator for that in C++.

Comment: @chris I think you should answer this question and gain credits

Comment: @BibooChung, There's already an answer that mentions the extension :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the fact that a Boolean expression results in 0 or 1 and use

```
int f(int a) {
    return (a > -1) * (a + 1);
}
```

If `(a > -1)` is true then we have `1 * (a + 1)` otherwise we have `0 * (a + 1)`.

I would not suggest doing this though.  Clear code should be one of the big things you try to maintain in you code.  Using a well know syntax like `condition ? true_result : false_result` is better IMHO.

EDIT:

If you want the value to be something other than zero then it gets a little more complicated.  You would need to add to the return value the value of the false condition times a Boolean expression that is only true when the true condition is false(a not condition).

```
int f(int a) {
    return ((a % 2) * (a % 2)) + (!(a % 2) * (a * 2));
    //     ^    true part    ^   ^    false part    ^
}
```

With this when the `true part` is `0` the `false part` will be a value and when the `false part` is `0` the `true part` will be a value.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've modified the question in order to make it clear so you may have to modify your answer also.

Comment: @BibooChung It is still the same type of thing.  Multiply whatever you want in the true case against a condition that is only true when you want that value.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, you are right but what if I don't want to return 0 if the condition is false.

Comment: @BibooChung I updated the code.  Again I would not use this but I figured it should at least be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Just write a function:

```
template<typename T>
T conditional( T &&v1, T &&v2 )
{
   return v1 ? v1 : v2;
}

int f( int a )
{
    return conditional( a%2, a*2 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on gcc, there's an [extension for that](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html):

```
int f(int a) {
    return (a%2) ? : (a*2);
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
int f(int a) {
    return (a%2) ? (a%2) : (a*2);
}
```

Clang seems to support it too. But really the compiler will probably do the right thing for you if you duplicate the expression. At the very least, this:

```
int f(int a) {
    auto&& expr = a%2;
    return expr ? expr : (a*2);
}
```

is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that function always returns `a+1`. If `a+1` is 0, you say you return 0, which is also `a+1`.

To answer what you mean though, you can always just do a bit of math if you prefer: `!!cond * res1 + !cond * res2` for the general case of `cond ? res1 : res2`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've modified the question in order to make it clear so you may have to modify your answer also.